# android you don't have permission to access / on this server WAMP

Tags: php, android, apache, wampserver

im trying to open my wamp server with my android device but i get "android you don't have permission to access / on this server" apache version is 2.4.18.i tryed to modify httpd.conf but it doesnt work.Now its like this:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

    # onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For newer versions of WampServer (3.0+) you do not need to two things :

1) Modify the file `httpd.conf` 
   Go to directory where wamp is installed eg

`C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf` and edit the following :

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#

#onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```

Edit **Require none** to **Require all granted**

2) Now go to `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf` and do the same change to the Virtual Host defined for localhost

```
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Restart the server it should work

Comment: This is the answer...Thanks.